# disable background in jquery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modalpopup

OK, So i have this snippet  http://jsfiddle.net/8vFEd/   here;

whenever the popup comes up, I either want to disable the background, so that users can't click on another language until they close the first popup, or how would I accomplish that, whenever users click on second language, the first popup disappears and its corresponding popup  appears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My suggestion would be to put an overlay over the background which will "catch" clicks through to the rest of the page. Add the following to your $('.prop a').click() function, before the `<div class='lang'>` append call:

```
$("body").append('<div class="modalOverlay">');
```

and this to your css:

```
.modalOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* black semi-transparent */
}
```

Then in your code for handling "close" clicks, remove this .modalOverlay from the DOM. Remember to add the overlay before your popup window so it sits behind  the window (or add "z-index: 5" to your overlay css and "z-index: 6" to your popup css)

I would also suggest modifying your `.lang` css rule to be `position: absolute;` or `fixed` instead of relative.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at beginning of your onclick

```
$(".lang").remove();
```

That will remove or clear the div with lang class before repainting the DOM with a new one.