# Disable the popup background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

here my code is:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pop").click(function(){             
            $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000); 
            positionPopup(); 
        }); 
        function positionPopup()
        {
            if(!$("#overlay_form").is(':visible')){
                return;
            }
            $("#overlay_form").css({
                left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
                top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
                position:'absolute'
            });
        }
        $(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);
    </script>
    <style>
        #overlay_form{position: absolute;border: 5px solid gray;padding: 10px;background: white; width: 380px;height: 120px;border-radius:20px;}
    </style>
    <div id="overlay_form" style="display:none;">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
```

I need to disable background click events.

Comment: What do you mean by background click?

Comment: Try http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: I edited your code to make it cleaner with indentation. You can see that `$(document).ready(function(){` is never closed.

Comment: This is due to bubble events.You can find solution by referring http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 1):

inside click handler:

```
$("#pop").click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#overlay_form").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by covering the entire page with an overlay just below your popup. Add this code just before you open your popup.

```
$("body").append('<div class="modalOverlay">');
```

and css

```
.modalOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* black semi-transparent */
}
```

Then When you close your popup window just remove this div from page.

Comment: Original answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185469/disable-background-in-jquery-popup). I see this as a clean way to do what you wanted with out any change in your html.

Comment: Or if you are open to JqueryUI then you can use the [dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).